# char* or char ?. I don't understand about the declaration here

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I wrote a function that cuts all the left space of an inputted string. These two functions give the same output "haha" when input is "  haha".
My question are:

1) Why the 1st one need return but the 2nd one doesn't. I added "return s" and it made a syntax error.

2) Are there any different in these if I use it in another situation?

3) Many said that 2nd one return a character not a string, how about my output ?

```
char *LTrim(char s[])               
{
    int i=0;
    while(s[i]==' ')i++;
    if (i>0) strcpy(&s[0],&s[i]);
    return s;
}
```

and

```
char LTrim(char s[])                
{
    int i=0;
    while(s[i]==' ')i++;
    if (i>0) strcpy(&s[0],&s[i]);
}
```

This is my main():

```
int main()
{
   char s[100];
   printf("input string ");
   gets(s);
   LTrim(s);
   puts(s); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what pointers are?

Comment: Do not do `strcpy(&s[0],&s[i]);` because `strcpy()` won't accept overlapped buffer and passing overlapped buffer will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: How can they give you "same output" if only one of them returns something?

Comment: @ScottHunter you can get the same output, but only because of undefined behaviour.

Comment: Show the part of the program where you call `LTrim`.

Comment: @ScottHunter and also can get the same output if the op doesn't use the return value (we don't know that because the calling code is missing).

Comment: @Arc676 I'm beginning with programming. If you ask me like that you can find the next question that satisfy your knowledge ??

Comment: @MichaelWalz:
main()
{
 char s[100];
 printf("input string ");
 gets(s);
 LTrim(s);
 puts(s); 
}

Comment: @VuVAnh please update your question instead of positing your code in a comment

Comment: @MichaelWalz: thank you for remind me doing that. I updated it.

Comment: As @MikeCAT says, don't use `strcpy()` on an overlapping buffer. You need to use `memmove()` and `strlen()` instead: `memmove(&s[0], &s[i], strlen(&s[i]) + 1);`. Or more succinctly: `memmove(s, s + i, strlen(s + i) + 1);`. (EDIT: Added +1 to `strlen` to copy the null-terminator.)

Comment: @IanAbbott Please use `memmove(s, s + i, strlen(s + i) + 1);` to include the terminating null character to what is copied.

Comment: @MikeCAT, Yes, I realized my mistake shortly after posting!

Answer (score 1):

Your second code segment doesn't seem to have a return statement, please correct that for getting the correct answer.

The first function is returning a character pointer, which will be memory pointing to the starting location of your character array s, whereas the second function is returning a single character.

What you do with the values returned is what will make the difference, both the codes seem to be performing the same operation on the character array(string) passed to them, so if you are only looking at the initial and final string, it will be same.

On the other hand, if you actually use the returned value for some purpose, then you will get a different result for both functions.

Comment: I try to write "return s" in the 2nd one but it gave me "invalid conversion from char* to char".
both of them give me the same output "haha" if input "   haha".
Thank you so much. I think I'm a bit clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

**`char *LTrim(char s[]){}`** is a function of character array / string which returns **`character pointer`** i.e. returns **`reference / memory address`**.

While **`char LTrim(char s[])`** is a function of character array / string, which return **`character`** only.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question , and I confused that my output give me a string for both of functions, not character.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is a single character.
`char *` is a pointer to a char.

`char *` are mostly used to point to the first character of a string (like `s`in your example).

In the first example you return your modified `s`variable, and in the second you return nothing so it's best to change the return value to `void` instead of `char`.

Comment: Thanks.I tried to write "return s" in the 2nd one but it said invalid conversion from char* to char.

Comment: You can't convert a `car *`to `char`directly. But you can use `*s`which will return the `char` pointed by your `char *s`.

Comment: OK it works now. I see that when I write " return s" which is s is the pointer when declare char s[] , it made the invalid conversion. when use " return *s" it's return string. Thank you so much.

Comment: The `return *s`statement will return the first character of the string which is a `char`.